# syntax error in mysql update query my syntax is correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, syntax-error

```
<?php
$query2 = "update likeusers set like='$likeid' where uid='$uid'";
mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_affected_rows();
echo $count;
```

ERROR: incorrect syntax near 'like=...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`like` is a reserved word in SQL. The best advise would be to rename this column. If this is not possible, you can escape it using backticks:

```
$query2="update likeusers set `like`='$likeid' where uid='$uid'";
```

Side note:
Using string replacement in SQL like this leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.